# " 'hdfs' is not recognized as an internal or external command, operable program or batch file"

Tags: hadoop, installation

I am on the final stage of installing hadoop and when I try to run the commands this error occurs. Can anyone help me solve this?

Comment: Anurag, could you give us more specifics.

Answer (score 0):

This is a Windows error that indicates your PATH doesn't properly have `%HADOOP_HOME%\bin` defined

Personally, my recommendation is to always use Linux environments for Hadoop since this is almost always what it'll be if you used it for a job.